# Is there anyway to scrape a csk?

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
<td class="left " data-append-csv="adamja01" data-stat="player" csk="Adam,Jason0.01"><a href="/players/a/adamja01.shtml">Jason&nbsp;Adam</a></td>
```

This is the code I have so far... I would like Adam, Jason imported into excel. It looks like his name is located in 'csk'. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = urlopen("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-pitching.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.read(),"lxml")
tags = soup.findAll('div')
for t in tags:
    print(t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lxml` will be much faster:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
from lxml import html

response = urlopen("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-pitching.shtml")
content = response.read()

tree = html.fromstring( content )

#Now we need to find our target table (comment text)
comment_html = tree.xpath('//comment()[contains(., "players_standard_pitching")]')[0]

#removing HTML comment markup
comment_html = str(comment_html).replace("-->", "")
comment_html = comment_html.replace("<!--", "")

#parsing our target HTML again
tree = html.fromstring( comment_html )

for pitcher_row in tree.xpath('//table[@id="players_standard_pitching"]/tbody/tr[contains(@class, "full_table")]'):

    csk = pitcher_row.xpath('./td[@data-stat="player"]/@csk')[0]
    print(csk)
```

Comment: When I tried adding the line for pitcher_row... I received this error:    for pitcher_row in tree.xpath('//table[@id="players_standard_pitching"]/tbody/tr[contains(@class, "full_table")]'):
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @JakeWest Please show your full code because I have tested my version and it's 100% correct

Comment: I originally tried line by line using jupyter and ran into that error. I just tried it again on the python shell and it worked perfectly. You are amazing!!! I can't thank you enough!!! =) Would it be difficult to add the other stat categories, too? No worries if it is. I will study this code and see if I can figure it out. Thanks again @gangabass!

Comment: @JakeWest It's not difficult at all. Just learn about XPath and add expressions you need.

Comment: I will do as you suggest. I am very grateful for this advice @gangabass! Is there a way to contact you for future work?

Comment: You're right @gangabass... I will review XPath tonight like you recommended. I have no experience with coding but I enjoy learning. My friend and hoping to turn a hobby into a business someday. Perhaps you would have some interest in helping out. Thank you so much for your time! =)

Comment: @gangabass....did you use firefox or chrome to find those X Paths? Do you recommend any downloads or plugins to help with finding the best X Path? I used Google Chrome but my X Path looked different than yours. I am new so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for everything!

Comment: @JakeWest you are asking for a help but even didn't accept my answer. I used Chrome but it will not show your XPath above. You need to analyze HTML and "generate" it by yourself

Comment: you make this sound really easy...do you have any videos or websites that you would recommend for learning how to generate the XPath or to learn web scraping? I am watching/reading from multiple sources. It seems like so many people have different approaches. Thank you for your time!  =)

Comment: @JakeWest You can check corresponding tags (`web-scraping`, `xpath` etc) here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script to get them. The data you are willing to grab are within comment that is why usual approach doesn't let you collect them:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

content = urlopen("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-pitching.shtml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.read(),"lxml")
for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(comment,"lxml")
    for tags in sauce.find_all('tr'):
        name = [item.get("csk") for item in tags.find_all("td")[:1]]
        print(name)
```

Comment: I received this error... File "<ipython-input-13-9e979913de31>", line 1
    for comment in soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)):
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: It happens usually when there is any bracket missing. Check out that in your script. The one I've provided above should not throw you that error cause I've checked again. Btw, the above script is for python 3 or above.

Comment: the code worked... I am just really bad at coding haha. Thanks! =)

Comment: how did you know to use this approach? I am not sure how to tell that the text is within comment. Thanks for your time! =)